# USB device refuses to work after working for one time

Tags: usb, dmesg

I have a Playstation 2 controller with a USB adapter plugged into my computer. The very first time I tried the adapter + controller it worked just fine. However, after rebooting the computer it doesn't work anymore. I've also tried re-plugging the adapter and plugging it into different USB ports but no luck.

This is what I find in dmesg:

```
[ke heinä 26 12:06:40 2023] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[ke heinä 26 12:06:40 2023] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=2563, idProduct=0523, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ke heinä 26 12:06:40 2023] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ke heinä 26 12:06:40 2023] usb 1-8: Product: PS3/PC Gamepad
[ke heinä 26 12:06:40 2023] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: ShanWan
[ke heinä 26 12:06:40 2023] input: ShanWan PS3/PC Gamepad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:2563:0523.33F45/input/input212862
[ke heinä 26 12:06:41 2023] hid-generic 0003:2563:0523.33F45: input,hidraw9: USB HID v1.10 Joystick [ShanWan PS3/PC Gamepad] on usb-0000:00:14.0-8/input0
[ke heinä 26 12:06:41 2023] usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 15
[ke heinä 26 12:06:41 2023] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[ke heinä 26 12:06:42 2023] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=2563, idProduct=0523, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ke heinä 26 12:06:42 2023] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ke heinä 26 12:06:42 2023] usb 1-8: Product: PS3/PC Gamepad
[ke heinä 26 12:06:42 2023] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: ShanWan
[ke heinä 26 12:06:42 2023] input: ShanWan PS3/PC Gamepad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:2563:0523.33F46/input/input212863
[ke heinä 26 12:06:42 2023] hid-generic 0003:2563:0523.33F46: input,hidraw9: USB HID v1.10 Joystick [ShanWan PS3/PC Gamepad] on usb-0000:00:14.0-8/input0
[ke heinä 26 12:06:42 2023] usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 16
[ke heinä 26 12:06:42 2023] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[ke heinä 26 12:06:43 2023] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=2563, idProduct=0523, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ke heinä 26 12:06:43 2023] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ke heinä 26 12:06:43 2023] usb 1-8: Product: PS3/PC Gamepad
[ke heinä 26 12:06:43 2023] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: ShanWan
[ke heinä 26 12:06:43 2023] usbhid 1-8:1.0: can't add hid device: -71
[ke heinä 26 12:06:43 2023] usbhid: probe of 1-8:1.0 failed with error -71
[ke heinä 26 12:06:43 2023] usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 17
[ke heinä 26 12:06:43 2023] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[ke heinä 26 12:06:44 2023] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=2563, idProduct=0523, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ke heinä 26 12:06:44 2023] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ke heinä 26 12:06:44 2023] usb 1-8: Product: PS3/PC Gamepad
[ke heinä 26 12:06:44 2023] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: ShanWan
[ke heinä 26 12:06:44 2023] input: ShanWan PS3/PC Gamepad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:2563:0523.33F47/input/input212864
[ke heinä 26 12:06:44 2023] hid-generic 0003:2563:0523.33F47: input,hidraw9: USB HID v1.10 Joystick [ShanWan PS3/PC Gamepad] on usb-0000:00:14.0-8/input0
[ke heinä 26 12:06:44 2023] usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 18
[ke heinä 26 12:06:44 2023] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[ke heinä 26 12:06:45 2023] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=2563, idProduct=0523, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ke heinä 26 12:06:45 2023] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ke heinä 26 12:06:45 2023] usb 1-8: Product: PS3/PC Gamepad
[ke heinä 26 12:06:45 2023] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: ShanWan
[ke heinä 26 12:06:45 2023] input: ShanWan PS3/PC Gamepad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:2563:0523.33F48/input/input212865
[ke heinä 26 12:06:45 2023] hid-generic 0003:2563:0523.33F48: input,hidraw9: USB HID v1.10 Joystick [ShanWan PS3/PC Gamepad] on usb-0000:00:14.0-8/input0
[ke heinä 26 12:06:45 2023] usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 19
[ke heinä 26 12:06:46 2023] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
[ke heinä 26 12:06:46 2023] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=2563, idProduct=0523, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ke heinä 26 12:06:46 2023] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ke heinä 26 12:06:46 2023] usb 1-8: Product: PS3/PC Gamepad
[ke heinä 26 12:06:46 2023] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: ShanWan
[ke heinä 26 12:06:46 2023] input: ShanWan PS3/PC Gamepad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:2563:0523.33F49/input/input212866
[ke heinä 26 12:06:46 2023] hid-generic 0003:2563:0523.33F49: input,hidraw9: USB HID v1.10 Joystick [ShanWan PS3/PC Gamepad] on usb-0000:00:14.0-8/input0
[ke heinä 26 12:06:46 2023] usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 20
[ke heinä 26 12:06:47 2023] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
[ke heinä 26 12:06:47 2023] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=2563, idProduct=0523, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ke heinä 26 12:06:47 2023] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ke heinä 26 12:06:47 2023] usb 1-8: Product: PS3/PC Gamepad
[ke heinä 26 12:06:47 2023] usb 1-8: can't set config #1, error -71
[ke heinä 26 12:06:47 2023] usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 21
```

with similar stuff going on forever... apparently it's trying to connect the device over and over again and keeps failing.

Comment: Hardware misbehaving. Not fixable through software.